# Trigger and procedure with iteretion over rows

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, procedure, mariadb

I have two tables `products` and `companies`. Each product belongs to one company. Also each product can have some keywords. Keywords are stored in column i products table and are seperated by space.

I would like to have company name in `keywords` field at last position. I am writing trigger and procedure for resolving my goal.

I have created following trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `update_product_keywords_after_update_companies`
AFTER UPDATE ON `companies`
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        set @company_id = new.id;
        set @company_new_name = new.company_name;
        set @company_old_name = old.company_name;

        CALL update_product_keywords_by_company_name(@company_id, @company_old_name, @company_new_name);
    END
;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

And the procedure looks as follows:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE update_product_keywords_by_company_name(IN company_id INT(10) UNSIGNED, IN company_old_name VARCHAR(120), IN company_new_name VARCHAR(120))
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE keywords TEXT;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT `keywords` FROM `products` WHERE `company_id` = company_id;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN cur;
    -- iterate over every product of that company
    REPEAT
        FETCH cur INTO keywords;
        IF NOT done THEN
            IF (keywords LIKE concat('%', company_old_name))
            THEN
                -- if keywords contains old company name, replace it with new company name
                UPDATE `products` SET `keywords` = REPLACE(keywords, company_old_name, company_new_name) WHERE `products`.`company_id` = company_id;
            ELSE
                -- if keywords does not contain old company name, appen new company name at the end of keywords
                UPDATE `products` SET `keywords` = CONCAT_WS(' ', keywords, company_new_name) WHERE `products`.`company_id` = company_id;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    UNTIL done END REPEAT;

    CLOSE cur;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Unfortunately, my procedure always updates every product (of company) keywords by clearing it and adding only new company name. Even if there were some keywords earlier, they are being removed.

I am using MariaDB 10. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid naming variables and parameter as columns of your tables.

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `update_product_keywords_after_update_companies`
AFTER UPDATE ON `companies`
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        /*
        set @company_id = new.id;
        set @company_new_name = new.company_name;
        set @company_old_name = old.company_name;
        */

        /*
        CALL update_product_keywords_by_company_name(@company_id, @company_old_name, @company_new_name);
        */

        CALL update_product_keywords_by_company_name(NEW.`id`, OLD.`company_name`, NEW.`company_name`);
    END//

DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //

/*
CREATE PROCEDURE update_product_keywords_by_company_name(IN company_id INT(10) UNSIGNED, IN company_old_name VARCHAR(120), IN company_new_name VARCHAR(120))
*/
CREATE PROCEDURE `update_product_keywords_by_company_name`(
     IN `_company_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED,
     IN `company_old_name` VARCHAR(120),
     IN `company_new_name` VARCHAR(120)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE keywords TEXT;
    /*
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT `keywords` FROM `products` WHERE `company_id` = company_id;
    */
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT `keywords`
    FROM `products`
    WHERE `company_id` = `_company_id`;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    OPEN cur;
    -- iterate over every product of that company
    REPEAT
        FETCH cur INTO keywords;
        IF NOT done THEN
            IF (keywords LIKE concat('%', /*company_old_name*/ `company_old_name`))
            THEN
                -- if keywords contains old company name, replace it with new company name
                UPDATE `products`
                SET `keywords` = REPLACE(keywords, /*company_old_name*/ `company_old_name`, /*company_new_name*/ `company_new_name`)
                WHERE `products`.`company_id` = /*company_id*/ `_company_id`;
            ELSE
                -- if keywords does not contain old company name, appen new company name at the end of keywords
                UPDATE `products`
                SET `keywords` = CONCAT_WS(' ', keywords, /*company_new_name*/ `company_new_name`)
                WHERE `products`.`company_id` = /*company_id*/ `_company_id`;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    UNTIL done END REPEAT;

    CLOSE cur;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```